# Wordpress: Added sidebar - random div being generated above widgets?

Tags: wordpress, widget, sidebar

I've added a new sidebar to my theme. It works, but a strange div with a height is appearing above any widgets I add to it:

```
<div id="blogsidebar">
   <ul>
      <div style="height: 280px;"></div>   <---???
      <li>WIDGET HERE</li>
  </u>
</div>
```

My sidebar.php code is:

```
<div id="blogsidebar">
   <ul>
      <?php
      if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('blog-sidebar') ) :
      endif; ?>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I have checked for any JQuery thats adding this and found none. Would anyone know why this is occurring?

Comment: Inspect your `functions.php` file.

Comment: @DimaKnivets You're right. It was in the register. Want to make that an answer?

Comment: What do you mean by register? Is there any need to make this an answer? :)

Comment: register_sidebar(array(..... 'before_widget' => '<div style="height:200px"></div><li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',